# can't find file in ubuntu running python

Tags: python

labels.csv exists in core_service

```py
labels_filename="labels.csv",                    
if os.path.isfile(labels_filename) == False:
    raise Exception("Can't find %s" % labels_filename)
```

```py
raise Exception("Can't find %s" % labels_filename)
Exception: Can't find core_service\labels.csv
```

Comment: You set `labels_filename="labels.csv"` but it prints `core_service\labels.csv`? Forward slashes "/" are file path delimiters in Linux.

Comment: If you are on windows, make sure you have escaped the ```\``` in the path.

Comment: I am trying to run it on ubuntu

Comment: If on *nix (Ubuntu), use forward slashes as path separators: `core_service/labels.csv`.

Answer (score -1):

- Use `os.getcwd()` (https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.getcwd) to show where your code is executing
- And `os.listdir()` to display the list of files directly accessible.